# Problemas con las rutas protegidas en React

Tags: reactjs, rutas

El problema que tengo es el siguinte: estoy haciendo que solo se pueda accerder a las rutas si el usuario esta logeado, caso contrario me redirije a la landing page para poder loguearse, pero uandotrato de acceder a /favorites, automaticamente me redirige al Home (porque el usuario esta loguead). Puse un consolo.log en el componente Favorites par ver como me llega la propiedad isAuthenticated desde el AuthProvider y puedo ver que llega en false. Ahora no pueod darme cuenta por para ir a Favorites se conviernte en false y para las otra no.

Este es el AuthProvider:

```
import { useContext, createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import React from "react";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import axios from "axios";
// import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
// import { getUser } from "../Redux/actions";
const AuthContext = createContext({
  isAuthenticated: false,
});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  console.log(isAuthenticated);
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null);
  // console.log(userId);

  useEffect(() => {
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
    if (accessToken) {
      const decodedToken = jwt_decode(accessToken);
      setUserId(decodedToken.id);
      // console.log(decodedToken);
      const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
      // console.log(currentTime);

      if (decodedToken.exp < currentTime) {
        const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem("refreshToken");
        if (refreshToken) {
          const refreshTokenOnserver = async () => {
            try {
              const data = await axios.post(
                "http://localhost:3001/refreshtoken",
                { refreshToken }
              );
              if (data.statusText === "OK") {
                const { accessToken: newAccessToken } = data;
                console.log(data);
                localStorage.setItem("accessToken", newAccessToken);
                setIsAuthenticated(true);
              } else {
                const errorData = data;
                console.log("Token refresh error:", errorData.message);
                localStorage.removeItem("accessToken");
                localStorage.removeItem("refreshToken");
                setIsAuthenticated(false);
              }
            } catch (error) {
              console.error("Error during token refresh:", error);
              localStorage.removeItem("accessToken");
              localStorage.removeItem("refreshToken");
              setIsAuthenticated(false);
            }
          };
          refreshTokenOnserver();
        } else {
          setIsAuthenticated(false);
        }
      } else {
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
      }
    }
  }, []);

  const logOut = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("accessToken");
    localStorage.removeItem("refreshToken");
    setIsAuthenticated(false);
    setUserId(null);
    // dispatch(logOut());
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        isAuthenticated,
        setIsAuthenticated,
        logOut,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);
```

este es ProtectedRoute:

```
import { Outlet, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "../../AuthProvider/AuthProvider";

export const ProtectedRoute = ({ element }) => {
  const auth = useAuth();
  return auth.isAuthenticated ? element : <Navigate to="/" />;
};
```

Y este es App:

```
import "./App.css";
import { Routes, Route, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { Home } from "./Views/Home/Home";
import Landing from "./Views/Landing/Landing";
import Detail from "./Views/Detail/Detail";
import Navbar from "./Components/Navbar/Navbar";
import Activity from "./Views/Activity/Activity";
import Activities from "./Views/Activities/Activities";
import Update from "./Components/UpdateActivity/Update";
import SignUp from "./Views/SignUp/SignUp";
import { AuthProvider } from "./AuthProvider/AuthProvider";
import { ProtectedRoute } from "./Components/ProtectedRoutes/ProtectedRoutes";
import Footer from "./Components/Footer/Footer";
import Favorites from "./Views/Favorites/Favorites";

function App() {
  const location = useLocation();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AuthProvider>
        {location.pathname !== "/" && location.pathname !== "/signup" && (
          <Navbar />
        )}

        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Landing />} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
          <Route path="/home" element={<ProtectedRoute element={<Home />} />} />
          <Route
            path="/countries/:id"
            element={<ProtectedRoute element={<Detail />} />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/activity"
            element={<ProtectedRoute element={<Activity />} />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/activities"
            element={<ProtectedRoute element={<Activities />} />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/favorites"
            element={<ProtectedRoute element={<Favorites />} />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/:id/update"
            element={<ProtectedRoute element={<Update />} />}
          />
        </Routes>
        {location.pathname !== "/" && location.pathname !== "/signup" && (
          <Footer />
        )}
      </AuthProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

El componente Favorites no lo muestro porque solo tiene un mensaje que dice Favoritos. Aclaro cque con el resto de las rutas la proteccion me funciona de manera correcta.